# List does not get populated with WebElements when method is called the third time

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have some code which returns the indexes of `WebElements` whose text match a provided string. The `WebElements` are fetched and placed in a list called `names`. The method is called a few times and for some reason, on the third call, the `WebElements` are not retrieved. While in debug mode, when the line of code that attempts to fetch the `WebElements` is run, there is a short 3-4 second delay and then moves on to the next line without fetching anything. I'm not sure why this is happening as there are no error messages. So `names` remains empty. I don't understand why this would happen, especially if it worked on the previous two method calls. I would be grateful for any help.  Here is my code:

This is the method I described:

```
public void getIndexOfItems(String ingredient) {
        indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //List<WebElement> names = product.products().get(0);
        List<WebElement> names = null;
        if(itemName.equalsIgnoreCase("Moisturiser")) {
            names = ((MoisturiserPage)product).findAll(MoisturiserPage.byNames);
        } else {
            names = ((SunscreenPage)product).findAll(SunscreenPage.byNames);
        }
        
        //List<WebElement> names = items.get(0);
        
        
        for(int i=0; i<names.size(); i++) {  
            String name = names.get(i).getText().toLowerCase();
            if(name.indexOf(ingredient) != -1) {
                indexes.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue where `findAll()` returns nothing when called for the third time happens here:

```
if(itemName.equalsIgnoreCase("Moisturiser")) {
            names = ((MoisturiserPage)product).findAll(MoisturiserPage.byNames);
        } else {
            names = ((SunscreenPage)product).findAll(SunscreenPage.byNames);
        }
```

Here is the Interface for the page objects:

```
package com.weathershopper.pageobjects;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public interface IProductPage {
    static By byNames = By.xpath("//div[@class='container']//p[@class='font-weight-bold top-space-10']");
    By byPrice = By.xpath("//div[@class='text-center col-4']/p[2]");
    By byAddBtn = By.xpath("//div[@class='text-center col-4']/button");
    By byCartBtn = By.xpath("//button[@class='thin-text nav-link']");
    By byCartText = By.xpath("//span[@id='cart']");
    
    List<List<WebElement>> products();
    void clickCart();
    void addToCart(Integer i);
    

}
```

Here is the `findAll()` method:

```
public List<WebElement> findAll(By by) {
        return driver.findElements(by);
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure where exactly you're getting NullPointerException?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Apologies, I don't get a NullPointerException but the list of WebElements does not get stored in the 'names' variable on the third call of the method. It works ok when called the first two times. Its on this line:                                                         
 names = ((MoisturiserPage)product).findAll(MoisturiserPage.byNames);